# Use different value from JSON data instead of displayKey using Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js

I have started using Typeahead.js and am struggling to figure out a way of allowing a user to type and search for a company name, once selected input the associated company code.

**.json file:**

```
[{
    "company_name": "Facebook",
    "code": "fb",
}, {
    "company_name": "Google",
    "code": "goog",
}, {
    "company_name": "Yahoo",
    "code": "yhoo",
}, {
    "company_name": "Apple",
    "code": "aapl",
}, {
    "company_name": "Royal Mail",
    "code": "rmg.l",
}]
```

**.js Script:**

```
var stocks = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.code);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 3,
    prefetch: {
        url: 'javascripts/stockCodes.json',
        filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(stock) {
                return {
                    code: stock
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

stocks.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'stocks',
    displayKey: 'code',
    source: stocks.ttAdapter()
});
```

Currently, this just displays the list of codes when the user types in the input field. However, I would like to know if there is a way to allow them to search on `code` but once selected, the value in the textbox to be `company_name`? Is this even possible using this plugin. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to change your data structure?

Comment: @Tomanow Yes sure. I just thought this structure would be efficient. Thanks

Comment: I just updated my answer. It should be more accurate now.

Answer (score 35):

`displayKey` is used to indicate which key should be shown in the dropdown list **and** in the input field after the user has selected an entry.

If you want the entries shown in the dropdown list to be **different** from what ends up in the input field you need to use a custom template.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets):

> `suggestion` – Used to render a single suggestion. If set, this has to be a 
>   precompiled template. The associated suggestion object will serve as the
>   context. Defaults to the value of `displayKey` wrapped in a `p` tag i.e.
>   `<p>{{value}}</p>`.

Something like this should work:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'stocks',
    displayKey: 'company_name',
    source: stocks.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: function (stock) {
            return '<p>' + stock.code + '</p>';
        }
    }
});
```

The submitted template will be used to show `stock.code` in the dropdown list, while `stock.company_name` will be shown in the input field after the user selects an entry.

Answer (score 19):

I am no jQuery / JavaScript-Guru. So I prefer it the easy way. Just to understand what I did when I look at my code later...

Thanks to [Eric Saupe](http://ericsaupe.com/using-twitter-typeahead-js-custom-event-triggers/) I found a smart solution:

```
//JSON FILE
[
    {
        "company_name": "Facebook",
        "code": "fb",
    },
    {
        "company_name": "Google",
        "code": "goog",
    },
    {
        "company_name": "Yahoo",
        "code": "yhoo",
    },
    {
        "company_name": "Apple",
        "code": "aapl",
    },
    {
        "company_name": "Royal Mail",
        "code": "rmg.l",
    },
 ]
```

// JS SCRIPT

```
   var stocks = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: 'javascripts/stockCodes.json'
    });

    stocks.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(
        null, {
        name: 'stocks',
        displayKey: 'company_name',
        source: stocks.ttAdapter()
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
        $('.typeahead').val(data.code);        
    });
```

Just use the typeahead custom events as described in the [docs on github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events).

Hope, this helps (and when it's just for my own later reference).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7z9qA/)

Comment: You want to also handle 'typeahead:autocompleted'.

Comment: Seems like the best solution, but the JSFIDDLE doesn't work anymore. When clicking, it is writing the whole company name.

Comment: Is it `typeahead:selected` or `typeahead:select`? Official docs say the latter. Either way, I couldn't get the event to fire.  I added `alert(data.code);` to your fiddle and it didn't fire too. What should be the right way?

Comment: The JSFIDDLE works as expected for me. I tested with Firefox and Chrome. 
I cannot tell if it's :selected or :select. It worked for me with :selected
Meanwhile I switched over to jQuery Typeahead (http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/). It is well documented and feature-rich and the config is more straightforward (imho).

Comment: Even after using `setTimeout` method like: `setTimeout(function() { $('.typeahead').val(data.code); }, 1);`, it was changing the value back when leaving the input box. So, I had to move to @Esseb's template based solution.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the ´displayKey´ variable. See below copy-paste from the typeahead docs:

> *displayKey* – For a given suggestion object, determines the string representation of it. This will be used when setting the value of the input control after a suggestion is selected. Can be either a key string or a function that transforms a suggestion object into a string. Defaults to `value`.

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md

Your specific code would then be something like this:

```
var stocks = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.code); },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 3,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'javascripts/stockCodes.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                // This should not be required, but I have left it incase you still need some sort of filtering on your server response
                return $.map(list, function(stock) { return { code: stock.code, company_name: stock.company_name }; });
            }
        }
    });

    stocks.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'stocks',
        displayKey: function(stock) {
           return stock.company_name;
        },
        source: stocks.ttAdapter()
    });
```

I had a very similar requirement on my own site, and I had this working with no issue. I have not tried this particular example though, so let me know if it works.

Remember to call `stocks.clearPrefetchCache();` to clear your cache to easier track bugs.

Answer (score 4):

If I read correctly, I believe this is what you want:

```
var stocksData = [{
    "Facebook": "fb",
}, {
    "Google": "goog",
}, {
    "Yahoo": "yhoo",
}, {
    "Apple": "aapl",
}, {
    "Royal Mail": "rmg.l",
}, ];

var stocks = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                  for (var prop in d) {
                      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d[prop]);
                  }

    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 3,
    local: stocksData,
});

stocks.initialize();

$('input').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'stocks',
    displayKey: function(stocks) {
        for (var prop in stocks) {
            return prop;    
        }
    },
    source: stocks.ttAdapter()
});
```

You will of course want to change the local to prefetch/remote like you had for the json file.

**UPDATE**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5rCB7/1/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, much appreciated. I have only just gotten around to using the code provided in the fiddle above. I'm not sure if I explained the problem properly but I am trying to figure out how to place the associated value in the input text box as opposed the the key value. For example, typing 'Facebook' should show Facebook in the drop down list however, once selected, the text box value would show 'fb' instead of 'Facebook'. I have tried tweaking the code provided, but haven't managed to the incorporate this functionality yet. Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, could not get it working with the display or displayKey property. Worked around it by adding the name property to the source objects:

```
            $.each(stocks, function (i, item) {
                item.name = item.company_name;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the value that need to be shown in the **display** parameter:

```
$(".comp-search").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    displayKey: 'company_name',
}, {
    source: engine.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: ['<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'],
        header: ['<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'],
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">' + data.company_name + '</a>';
        }
    },
    display: function(data) { return data.company_name; }
});
```

Hope this is helpful