# Typeahead populating with all attributes of active record object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, typeahead.js

I am using rails 4 and I'm trying to get it to work with the latest typeahead.  The dropdown is showing all attributes of a matching active record object and not just the name like I want it to.

**`item.rb`**

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(['lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      Item.all
    end
  end
```

**`items_controller.rb`**

```
  def index
    @items= Item.search(params[:query])
  end

  def typeahead
    render json: Item.where('name ilike ?', "%#{params[:query]}%")
  end
```

**`_header.html.erb`**

```
.
.
.
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      limit: 10,  
      remote: {url: '/typeahead/%QUERY',
               wildcard: '%QUERY'}  
    });
    bloodhound.initialize();

    $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      name: 'name',
      source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
    });

    $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
      window.location.href = '/items/' + datum.id;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**`config/routes.rb`**

```
get 'typeahead/:query', to: 'items#typeahead'
```

I can go to /typeahead/:query.json and it seems to be working as it's supposed to.

Comment: @guest271314 tagging you so you can find my question

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: I want the typeahead to just show the name attribute but it is showing everything `{"id":4,"name":"Flexidy","description":"Impedit libero veniam sit molestias quae.","created_at":"2016-01-07T15:26:45.305Z","updated_at":"2016-01-07T15:26:45.305Z","created_by":null,"status":1}`

Comment: _"I want the typeahead to just show the name attribute."_ At dropdown , suggestions ?

Comment: Yes the dropdown suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets) at

> `display` – For a given suggestion, determines the string
>   representation of it. This will be used when setting the value of the
>   input control after a suggestion is selected. Can be either a key
>   string or a function that transforms a suggestion object into a
>   string. Defaults to stringifying the suggestion.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Flexidy",
    "description": "Impedit libero veniam sit molestias quae.",
    "created_at": "2016-01-07T15:26:45.305Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-07T15:26:45‌​.305Z",
    "created_by": null,
    "status": 1
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Plexidy",
    "description": "Impedit libero veniam sit molestias quae.",
    "created_at": "2016-01-07T15:26:45.305Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-07T15:26:45‌​.305Z",
    "created_by": null,
    "status": 1
  }];
  var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: $.map(data, function(item) {
      return {
        value: item.name
      }
    })
  });
  bloodhound.initialize();

  $('#typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true
  }, {
    name: 'name',
    display: 'name',
    limit: 10,
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var details = "<div>" + data.value + "</div>";
        return details
      }
    },
     source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  });

  // $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
  //   window.location.href = '/items/' + datum.id;
  // });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>



<div class="bs-example">
  <input type="text" id="typeahead" />
</div>
```

Comment: I need this to use remote data because it is part of a search in my website.  If I change my typeahead method to `render json: Item.where('name ilike ?', "%#{params[:query]}%").pluck(:name)` it works but then I don't have a way to pass the id which I need to generate the links because I want each suggestion clickable.

Comment: `local` used at stacksnippets for demonstration

Comment: I don't see how to I would change it to use remote and still use map.  It looks like the `remote` option used to have a `filter` property that could be used to map the remote source JSON array to a javascript array but I think that was removed.

Comment: @user4584963 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258673/bootstrap-typeahead-not-showing-suggestion-which-have-the-valuekey-starting-with

Comment: If I can't use `filter` is there another way I can convert json to a javascript array that is used by bloodhound?

Comment: @user4584963 Simplest approach would be to not use `typeahead.js` or `Bloodhound` , but use modified typeahed `substringMatcher` function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739881/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-when-using-typeahead-bloodhound/33765633#33765633

Comment: Turns out after all that my problem was I was missing `displayKey` http://stackoverflow.com/a/25485029/4584963.  Looks like this is being changed to `display` in latest version https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/typeahead/dataset.js (check line 47).  Thanks for all your time.  If you add this to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @user4584963 Interesting. Good finds. See updated post

Comment: Hate to be a stickler but could you just add the line `display: 'name'` under the `name` option in your typeahead code?

Comment: Should be placed under `minLength` or `name` ?

Comment: Under `name` as it is a dataset option.